# How can i fix these little v shaped cracks and pops in foundation?

Tags: concrete, repair, foundation, crack

I am not sure why these are here, but they don't appear to go below soil. There are a couple of them. How do I fix such a thing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: fill it up with concrete

Comment: You probably don't. It's hard to tell from the photo without some context, but the one pictured does not look to be significant. Probably only a cosmetic issue.

Comment: Can you show us a more 'zoomed-out' view along the length of the foundation and indicate roughly where and how many of these cracks are present?

Comment: @brhans I don't right now, but it's about 30 feet of foundation on each side and each has 2 cracks like this

Comment: @brhans also this house is from the 60s, just took over it in the spring. My guess is these cracks have been there a while